# How to Implement Boyer-Moore Search for Streams

Tags: php, algorithm, search, boyer-moore

How would I go about implementing [Boyer-Moore Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) for streams? I understand how to implement this for a given string where we know the length of the entire string. However, what if we have no idea the size of the string (*i.e it's an arbitrary length stream of bytes*).

I'm trying to implement this in PHP so any code in PHP would be helpful.

Here's the implementation of Boyer-Moore Search I have in PHP:

```
function BoyerMooreSearch($haystack, $needle) {
    $needleLen = strlen($needle);
    $haystackLen = strlen($haystack);
    $table = computeSkipTable($needle);

    for ($i = $needleLen - 1; $i < $haystackLen;) { 
        $t = $i;

        for ($j = $needleLen - 1; $needle[$j] == $haystack[$i]; $j--, $i--) { 
            if($j == 0) {
                return $i;
            }
        }

        $i = $t;

        if(array_key_exists($haystack[$i], $table)) {
            $i = $i + max($table[$haystack[$i]], 1);
        } else {
            $i += $needleLen;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function computeSkipTable($string) {
    $len = strlen($string);
    $table = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < $len; $i++) { 
        $table[$string[$i]] = $len - $i - 1; 
    }

    return $table;
}
```

This works fine if we give it a haystack string like `"barfoobazquix"` and a needle string like `"foo"`, it will return `3` as expected. However, what if the input haystack were a stream split into 4 byte chunks. The first chunk would be `"barf"`, which would return no match, the second would be `"ooba"` which also returns no match, and so on...

In this scenario we'd never be able to find the substring `"foo"` in any of the buffered chunks of the stream with the current implementation. I'm struggling to adapt the current implementation such that it would work even if the search string were split across multiple chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you only ever use the `$needleLen` most recent characters from the stream. So you can maintain a sliding window consisting of `$needleLen` characters and advance it as needed. Furthermore, `$haystackLen` is now unknown and should be replaced with EOF checks.

The code below is inefficient because sliding the window always takes `O(n)` regardless if we slide it by `n` characters or just 1. To achieve optimal sliding complexity, the `$window` should be implemented as a circular character buffer.

```php
// sample call
var_dump(BoyerMooreSearch(STDIN, 'foo'));

function BoyerMooreSearch($resource, $needle) {
    $needleLen = strlen($needle);
    $table = computeSkipTable($needle);

    // build the first window
    if (($window = buildWindow($resource, $needleLen)) === false) {
        // special case: the text is shorter than the pattern
        return false;
    }

    $i = 0;
    while (true) {
        // check for a match
        $j = $needleLen - 1;
        while ($j >= 0 && $needle[$j] == $window[$j]) {
            $j--;
        }
        if ($j < 0) {
            return $i;
        }

        // determine slide distance
        $t = $i;
        $last = substr($window, -1);
        if (array_key_exists($last, $table)) {
            $i = $i + max($table[$last], 1);
        } else {
            $i += $needleLen;
        }

        // slide the window
        if (($window = slideWindow($window, $resource, $i - $t)) === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Initializes the sliding window to length $len.
 *
 * @return string A string of length $len or false if the $resource contains
 * less than $len characters.
 */
function buildWindow ($resource, $len) {
    $result = '';
    while ($len--) {
        $result .= fgetc($resource);
    }
    return feof($resource) ? false : $result;
}

/**
 * Slides $window by $count positions into $resource.
 *
 * @return string The new window or false on EOF.
 */
function slideWindow(&$window, $resource, $count) {
    $window = substr($window, $count) // discard the first $count chars
        . fread($resource, $count);   // and read $count new chars
    return feof($resource) ? false : $window;
}
```

Comment: This works great. Just a quick note in your loop `while ($j >= 0 && $needle[$j] == $window[$j]) {` you have to consider that `$needle` can actually be larger than `$window` there so you should be careful not to get an undefined offset error. Other than that your solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: If `$needle` can be larger than `$window`, there is a bug in my reasoning and it should be fixed. :-) Can you give an example? My intention was (a) to return early if `buildWindow()` returns a window shorter than `$needleLen`, then (b) to return whenever `slideWindow()` fails to keep the window at that same length. Apologies if my code does something different.

Comment: Well, it appears that if the needle is partially found within the input and then fails in the middle (input = `"fo"` for example) you end up with an undefined offset error on line 19 somehow (which is that while loop). I didn't dig too deap into it, but if I add the condition `&& isset($window[$j])` before `$needle[$j] == $window[$j]` it stops giving that error. This happens when I type `"fo"` and hit enter, for example.

Comment: Ah, good catch. It seems to have to do with how `fread` works with `STDIN`, because `fread` returns with fewer characters than expected. If I put the same input in a file `a.txt` and pipe it with `a.php < a.txt`, then the error no longer occurs. The proper fix would be to replace the call to `fread` with `$count` calls to `fgetc`.